# Problems deploying Django app to Apache

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

I'm currently trying to deploy my django application to Apache for production. It is my first time.

I am using Python version 2.7, Django 1.6 and virtualenvwrapper for dependency management.
My system is a CentOS 6 distribution.

When running

```
./manage.py runserver
```

from my virtualenv shell I get no problems at all, everything works fine.

Running via Apache I receive the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

This leads me to think that it is my configuration inside apache that is incorrect (as it works fine without apache)

My configuration inside my httpd.conf file is as follows:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/Webapp/smartrecruitment/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /opt/Webapp:/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<Directory /opt/Webapp/smartrecruitment>
    <Files wsgi.py>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I followed instructions from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ to deploy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify [`WSGIPythonHome`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) in your Apache config. This will enable your virtualenv for app.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried this, however when I try to access the site I receive a new error: ImportError: No module named site

Comment: What value did you use for Python home?

Comment: Apologies, I did use an incorrect value for WSGIPythonHome (pointed at the Python binary instead of the folder) I have changed to the correct value and am still receiving the error posted in my original question.

Comment: Could you please paste whole config with `WSGIPythonHome`. Mare sure this directive is outside of `VirtualHost`.

Comment: The whole config is 1044 lines long. It is completely standard except the lines shown above which are right at the bottom. Not inside VirtualHost

Comment: Your `WSGIPythonHome` is `/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/`?

Comment: This Apache config looks OK to me. Are you sure you installed dependencies inside virtualenv?. Did you use `workon` before running `runserver`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54186/discussion-between-augier-and-alex-shkop).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a problem with virtualenv setup.
To resolve the issue I needed to:

```
yum install mysql-python
```

But this was throwing an error.

I had to:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

This also had a dependancy issue which was only resolved when I uninstalled mysql and reinstalled:

```
yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-sever mysql-libs
```

It worked after this.